# Como utilizar ng-messages para mostrar erros do $http?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estou conseguindo utilizar para realizar validações do input vazio,min de caracteres e max de caracteres,exemplo:

```
<form name="myForm">
  <div class="input-group">

    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cep" ng-model="cep" ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="20" placeholder="Digite o CEP" autofocus required>

    <span class="input-group-btn">
     <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" ng-click="buscar(cep)">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </button>
    </span>
  </div>
</form>


<div ng-messages="myForm.cep.$error">
  <div ng-message="required" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Campo não pode ser vazio.</div>
  <div ng-message="minlength" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Deve ser acima de 5 caracteres</div>
  <div ng-message="maxlength" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Deve possuir menos que 20 caracteres</div>
</div>
```

Agora preciso entender, como utilizar o mesmo serviço ng-message para mostrar uma messagem caso a minha requisição falhe exemplo:

```
var app = angular.module("buscaCEP",['ngMessages']);
app.controller("buscaCEPCtrl",function($scope,$http){
    $scope.buscar = function(cep){
        $http.get('https://viacep.com.br/ws/'+cep+'/json/').success(function(data){
            $scope.form = data;
        }).error(function(){
            console.log("Ocorreu um erro inesperado, verifique se os dados digitados estão corretos.");
        });
    };
});
```

No .error do http preciso enviar uma ação para mostrar a mensagem do console.log();

Exemplo funcionando no [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/9Ry6GfYqt2phUsW5iBFo?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver, como eu ainda sou um jovem padawan em angular não sei se é a forma correta ou um RTA Avançado :)

Utilizei `ng-class` assim:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" ng-class='{"invisible": !resCep}' role="alert">
    Ocorreu um erro inesperado, verifique se os dados digitados estão corretos.
</div>
```

E no `$scope` mudei assim:

```
$http.get('https://viacep.com.br/ws/' + cep + '/json/').success(function(data) {
  $scope.form = data;
  $scope.resCep = false;
}).error(function() {
  $scope.resCep = true; // mostre o alert
});
```

Veja funcionando no [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/9Ry6GfYqt2phUsW5iBFo?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que eu entendo do `ngMessage`, para criar uma validação que não é padrão, você precisaria vincular esta à uma diretiva customizada onde ela faria essa validação e consequentemente você consegue exibir o erro. Eu, pelo menos, desconheço um método de utilizar o `ng-messages` a partir de um `$scope`, por exemplo.

Exemplo:

```
<div ng-messages="myForm.cep.$error">
    <div ng-message="cepinvalido" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Cep inválido</div>
</div>
```

E um directive que faça essa validação integrado ao form, por exemplo:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="cep" ng-model="cep"  ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="20" placeholder="Digite o CEP" autofocus required cepinvalido>

app.directive("cepinvalido", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function(scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {
            ngModel.$validators.cepinvalido = function(modelValue) {
                //obter os dados e fazer o return caso não haja resposta do CEP
                    return false;

                //ou retornar os dados caso haja
                //Para isso precisaria expandir a lógica do form ou do directive
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Observações:

-Não cheguei a testar esse modelo de aplicação com serviço de `$http`, apenas utilizei para comparações básicas, como por exemplo, verificar se a senha em dois campos é a mesma, mas a ideia é essa.

-Uma melhoria, digamos assim, para suas mensagens seria de usar `$dirty` em conjunto com `$error`, assim a mensagem só aparece após interação com o formulário e não logo no inicio, antes do usuário interagir. Veja:

```
<div ng-messages="myForm.cep.$dirty && myForm.cep.$error">
```

Comment: Esse  `$dirty` tava tentando fazer ele e não sabia como...